# two click function one submit button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have submit button which is when it is clicked it will submit ('#quiz-question-answering-form')form ID and automatically redirect to url "/foo1" but i have one link ('.quiz-progress a') that have link "/foo2" .

can i make my link ('.quiz-progress a') a click function that can keep submit  ('#quiz-question-answering-form') ID form and automatically remove the redirect url "/foo1" and replace with "/foo2" url which is owned by my link ('.quiz-progress a')...?

this is my code so far but fail..:(

```
$('.quiz-progress a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $('#quiz-question-answering-form').submit();
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Use `$('#quiz-question-answering-form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();`

Comment: every page that we redirect for have id form $('#quiz-question-answering-form') your code is works but submit the id form from the after load page  "/foo2" not the first page  "/foo1" , what i need is it keep submit the ID form the first page( before load) and redirect to next page